# The 44th percentile is the .44th __?

Tags: percentile

I'm searching for a very simple word.

We are all familiar with the concept of the 44th percentile of a real, random variable. In a sense, percentile (parameterized by the random variable) is a function from [0, 100] to $\mathbb{R}$.

That's... kinda weird. I mean, a function from [0, 1] to the reals? OK. But 100 is too arbitrary. Is there a word that would complete the phrase: the .44th __ of that random variable?

Comment: Relevant: [Quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function)

Comment: @Chappers sure. My impression, though, is that ‘quantile’ doesn’t work in that sentence.

Comment: True, "quartile" seems to be used differently by itself.